# Alasql how to export data to csv

Tags: angularjs, csv, umbraco7, alasql

Okay, so keyResource pulls data from my C# controller as a List of comma separated values. When the button is clicked, the console does log this data but when I set the alasql query to keyResource or to data it says datasource 0 is undefined.

```
angular.module("umbraco")
.controller("ExportAllController", function($scope, $http, keyResource){
    $scope.exportAll = function ($scope) {
        keyResource.exportAll().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("AllDictionaryItems.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', []);
        });
    };
});
```

This is what I currently have ^

These are what I have tried:

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("ExportAllController", function($scope, $http, keyResource){
        $scope.exportAll = function ($scope) {
            keyResource.exportAll().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("AllDictionaryItems.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [$scope.exportAll]);
            });
        };
    });

angular.module("umbraco")
.controller("ExportAllController", function($scope, $http, keyResource){
    $scope.exportAll = function ($scope) {
        keyResource.exportAll().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("AllDictionaryItems.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [keyResource]);
        });
    };
});

angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("ExportAllController", function($scope, $http, keyResource){
        $scope.exportAll = function ($scope) {
            keyResource.exportAll().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("AllDictionaryItems.csv",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [data]);
            });
        };
    });
```

I'm not sure how to do this because when the console is logging the data, I don't know why it's not working when I'm exporting to CSV?

Comment: what data structure is your `data`? i.e what does it look like when you log to console

Comment: It's a string in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method will not work because you are not passing any data for it to export.

The reason, I think, your last attempt did not work because your `data` structure is wrong

Have a look at below jsfiddle I create, which shows how to create csv from array of string or array of json object.

http://jsfiddle.net/alantsai/h2wbbkm6/

see if you try construct your `data` into one of the structure, and you should be able to export csv file

Comment: see the following question: I've updated my issue, I now have the data as an array and a CSV is being downloaded but the data in the CSV is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790200/alasql-csv-pulling-through-functions

Comment: before going to your new question, does my current answer answers this question?

Comment: Technically yes it does, but my data is pulled through from a C# controller, so it's automatically through as a string, then it goes to form data, but now I'm just converting it into an array of strings, to then be stored in the CSV